# storing objects in hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am trying to store my object in Hazelcast map but its not working. It creates a new instance which i am able to see in console and mancenter as well. It also creates the map but it has nothing inside. Also, System.out.println (accountMap.get()) prints nothing.
I even tried by doing a put operation with simple string, still same result.

Here is my code:

```
userAccount user = new userAccount();
user.name = "pras";
user.pass = "12345";


HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance (new Config());
                Map<Integer, userAccount> accountMap = instance.getMap("userMap");
                accountMap.put(1, user);
                System.out.println (accountMap.get(1));
```

Comment: please share some logs

Comment: also share the Hazelcast config xml you had used.

Comment: did you find the reason

Answer (score 1):

Given:
    package com.hazelcast;

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class userAccount implements Serializable {
    String name;
    String pass;
}
```

And your code from above, I get the following output:

```
INFO: [192.168.1.70]:5701 [dev] [3.8.1] 

Members [1] {
    Member [192.168.1.70]:5701 - f8f3cf77-9b02-48b7-8a61-f353c40a6267 this
}

Apr 21, 2017 3:19:28 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [192.168.1.70]:5701 [dev] [3.8.1] [192.168.1.70]:5701 is STARTED
Apr 21, 2017 3:19:28 PM com.hazelcast.internal.partition.impl.PartitionStateManager
INFO: [192.168.1.70]:5701 [dev] [3.8.1] Initializing cluster partition table arrangement...
com.hazelcast.userAccount@70ab80e3
```

Hope this helps